# The following Python code does nothing and I wonder why

Tags: python, recursion

I tried this Python code from a book and it doesn't work. I also copy pasted it to make sure it was not my fault and still doesn't work. Other similar examples using turtle work perfectly but this one don't run. No error, no warning, it just does nothing.

What's wrong? I'm relatively new in Python.

```
import turtle


def draw_triangle(points, color, my_turtle):
    my_turtle.fillcolor(color)
    my_turtle.up()
    my_turtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    my_turtle.down()
    my_turtle.begin_fill()
    my_turtle.goto(points[1][0], points[1][1])
    my_turtle.goto(points[2][0], points[2][1])
    my_turtle.goto(points[0][0], points[0][1])
    my_turtle.end_fill()


def get_mid(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2)


def sierpinski(points, degree, my_turtle):
    color_map = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'yellow',
    'violet', 'orange']
    draw_triangle(points, color_map[degree], my_turtle)
    if degree > 0:
        sierpinski([points[0],
            get_mid(points[0], points[1]),
            get_mid(points[0], points[2])],
            degree - 1, my_turtle)
        sierpinski([points[1],
            get_mid(points[0], points[1]),
            get_mid(points[1], points[2])],
            degree - 1, my_turtle)
        sierpinski([points[2],
            get_mid(points[2], points[1]),
            get_mid(points[0], points[2])],
            degree - 1, my_turtle)


def main():
    my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    my_win = turtle.Screen()
    my_points = [[-100, -50], [0, 100], [100, -50]]
    sierpinski(my_points, 3, my_turtle)
    my_win.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Do you ever call `main()`? Python won't do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the script add the following code snippet, this is the coding convention.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you prefer a functional coding style, you can actually just add main() at the end of your existing code.

Comment: Yes is that! I didn´t know you have to call main. In C, you don´t have to.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the functions, but you've never called them. If you add a

```py
main()  # note that there is no indentation here
```

to the very end of the file then you'll actually run the `main` function and kick off execution.

Comment: It's best practice to surround that call in a `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: That´s is because Python is not that evident for people coming from C like languages. To my point of view the fact that main is not automatically called just like in C, doesn´t make any sense.

Comment: @ionecum Yeah, from the perspective of a compiled language it is a bit strange. Looking at it in the context of python as a scripting languages makes it make a bit more sense. Its entrypoint is the file itself, executing from the top down, the use of functions being entirely optional. Everything that lives in `main` could just be put at the end of the file (although people would look at you funny).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in python after defining a function you have to call it . Try Calling it at a certain place in the code because the Python interpreter runs code vertically line by line . You can call the function by trying - function() - wherever and whenever you want to run the program.

Comment: Yes, it's that. I never would have imagined that I had to call main. The book from which I took the code don't call it.